# Given a YouTube video, programmatically get its channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've found at least five Stack Overflow questions of the form "here is a YouTube channel, how do I programmatically obtain the videos on this channel?"

**I want to do the opposite: given a video, what channel did it come from?**

So far, I've looked for solutions on this in the official YouTube API. I've also looked at libraries like pafy. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

It looks like you can make a video request, then set:

`part=snippet`

This will return the `channelId`, among other things. I did a request like so:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=f8WsO__XcI0&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

and I get the response:

```
 {

 ...

 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"IHLB7Mi__JPvvG2zLQWAg8l36UU/Xn3r39kJJF0iqtZbqFIeFUTgC0Q\"",
   "id": "f8WsO__XcI0",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-13T21:20:53.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Rm3-HA",

 ...

 }
```